# get output from xcrun xctrace list devices

Tags: ios, xcode, jenkins, groovy, xcrun

On a jenkins pipeline, I execute:

```
def devicesText = sh(script: "xcrun xctrace list devices", returnStdout: true)
printf devicesText
```

which has strange behaviour, since it prints the output on the console but does not save the output in the variable. The console looks like this (the ids have been replaced with `XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX`):

```
+ xcrun xctrace list devices
== Devices ==
SAM Team - Build Server 2018 (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX)

== Simulators ==
Apple Watch Series 5 - 40mm (7.0) (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX)
Apple Watch Series 5 - 44mm (7.0) (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX)
iPad (7th generation) (13.5) (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX)
iPad Air (3rd generation) (13.5) (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX)
iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation) (13.5) (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX)
iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) (13.5) (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX)
iPad Pro (9.7-inch) (13.5) (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX)
iPhone 11 (13.5) (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX)
iPhone 11 Pro (13.5) (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX)
iPhone 11 Pro Max (13.5) (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX)
iPhone 6s (13.5) (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX)
iPhone 8 (13.5) (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX)
iPhone 8 Plus (13.5) (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX)
iPhone SE (2nd generation) (13.5) (XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX)
[Pipeline] echo
```

As you can see the echo is empty since it was not copied to the variable. How can I get the output to be saved in the variable?

(it used to work with the deprecated command `instruments -s devices`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Somehow `xcrun xctrace` prints the output to `stderr`.

So in order to get `stderr` logs in `stdout` simply redirect them to `stdout` with `2>&1`.

-> `xcrun xctrace list devices 2>&1 | grep -oE 'iPhone.*?[^\(]+' | head -1 | awk '{$1=$1;print}'`

Answer (score 1):

I had the a similar issue in xcodebuild with GitHub Actions.  My work around was to find a device with xcrun xctrace list devices and use it directly in the build command ex: -destination "platform=$platform,name=iPhone 8".

I tried to use a the default regEx and grep 1 line matching iPhone* but it never worked for me.

Comment: the problem is that I am unable to get access to what is printed to console and therefore cannot get a device (I want to use random devices each time)

Comment: It still works fine with `instruments -s devices` though.. it's just deprecated

Comment: oh instrument -s devices on my build with GitHub Actions failed the build. Here the original code using instruments that GitHub gave me.....device=`instruments -s -devices | grep -oE 'iPhone.*?[^\(]+' | head -1 | awk '{$1=$1;print}'` and here is my change to use xcrun..... device=`xcrun xctrace list devices | grep -oE 'iPhone.*?[^\(]+' | head -1 | awk '{$1=$1;print}'`.... I changed the grep to get rid of the ".". Hopefully this helps.  It should definitely print out the device list.